# Null pointer exception in android

Tags: android

I have the following code for my dialog box, I want to get some text from the alert box, but the below given code throws null pointer exception.

```
public EditText summarytext;
public Button done;
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.summaryalert);
    dialog.setTitle("Other");

    done=(ButtonfindViewById(R.id.btn);
    done.setOnClickListener(don);<----Nullpointer Exception
```

---

---

```
     private View.OnClickListener don=new  View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override          
public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(v==findViewById(R.id.btn)){
                    summarytext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.summarytext);
                    sumry=summarytext.getText().toString();
                    String display=""+sumry;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
     display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    }
```

---

---

### summary alert

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget31"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
android:gravity="center"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget60"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:text="Other(provide summary)"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
></TextView></TableRow>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget60"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/summarytext" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
>
</EditText>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget60"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:text="Done"
></Button>
</TableRow>
```

### mainlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget31"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget58"
android:layout_width="320px"
android:layout_height="65px"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget60"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/other" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:ems="15">
</EditText>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget42"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/submit"
android:layout_width="155px"
android:layout_height="41px"
android:text="Done"
android:layout_x="77px"
android:layout_y="313px"
>
</Button>
</TableRow>>
</TableLayout>
```

**Edit**

**solved..!**

include 'dialog'

> done=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn);

Comment: What is the error code? It will be much easier to figure thing out if you if you add the stack trace with your question.

Comment: hard to tell from this code. Does the exception occur when clicking the button or when displaying the message? In DDMS or Debug views you can see what row is throwing.

Comment: 02-10 03:16:04.657: WARN/System.err(2938): java.lang.NullPointerException
 yep during the onclick event

Comment: Which actual line is throwing the NullPointerException? If it's `sumry=summarytext.getText().toString();`, then you know that summartext is not being found, as explained by kosokund.

You should probably be using a DialogInterface click listener rather than a view clicklistener if you're handling button clicks on an alert dialog.

Comment: rahul, your answer helped me . +1 for your post

Comment: Rahul , have you any idea , how to set background image for dialog?

Comment: @user775 have you tried adding a background in the 'summary alert' layout. ie, the xml being used for the dialogue? that should work..but not sure never tried it..do let me know if it didn't work. All the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using dialog.findViewById(r.id.summarytext) you should also probably be using this for your done button also. But you'll have to make the call for that after your dialog.show(). On a side note you can use getApplicationContext() for your Toast instead of getBaseContext().

Comment: Yes if the id is declared in R.layout.summaryalert, the view can only be found with dialog.findViewById(), because the layout was affected to it.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById(int)` can return null if the specified id is not found in the layout.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)

Comment: Agreed. Which would point to a layout issue in the code or xml layout.